# Não está retornando o HTML no React

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Galera estou fazendo a Omni Stack 9 da Rocket Seat, onde Diego ensina a desenvolver uma copia do AirBnB porém para Devs. Estou fazendo a parte Web e conseguir fazer até a pagina de login tranquilo, está redirecionando para a dashboard tudo certinho! Mas quando executo a rota de Dashboard ou New (novo spot) não está me retornando nada! Na aula ele coloca um H1 só para mostrar a pagina e aparece o titulo certinho! [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei o H1 ali no return, mas não está retornando ele! Nenhum html que eu coloco ele retornar. E nem essa função que eu criei executa

---

Eu criei primeiro a pagina para o user poder fazer o login [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fiz um arquivo de rotas para poder ter a navegação pelo sistema [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da pagina de login eu redireciono para a pagina dashboards (que é o primeiro print) A pagina de login está toda funcionando perfeitamente e redirecionando normal! Mas as outras duas que criei Dashboards e New nem uma das duas me retorna o HTML quando eu coloco alguma coisa!

OBS: na pagina de login eu chamo a rota "dashboards" no plural. E no primeiro print está no singular, eu ja corrigir colocando no plural e mesmo assim não resolveu

Comment: boa noite, tente fazer retornar o valor dentro de aspas.
ex:`'<h1>Hello World</h1>'`;

Comment: Verifique onde está chamando a página. No caso o Console.log está retornando algo?
Coloque o código escrito. Imagem fica ruim de analisar/copiar/entender.
Coloque o trecho do código que está chamando a página.

Comment: @KaykyBruno coloquei as aspas e não foi e o console só me acusa a variavel que eu criei e não está sendo utilizado!

Comment: @RebecaNonato Estou chamando pela pagina de login! Vou editar a pergunta e colocar os prints e explicar minha intenção

Comment: @VictorSouza [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/459213/edit) sua pergunta, substituindo a imagem pelo código em si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica o \ na sua chamada no Routes.js.

```
<Route path="/dashboards" component={Dashboards} />
```

E no seu Routes.js as importações não precisam apontar para o index.js, somente para a Pasta em questão.

```
 import Logon from "./pages/Logon";
 import Profile from "./pages/Dashboards";
```

E muito cuidado. Pois você deve manter padrão de Nomenclatura, com o Maiúscula e Minúsculo. Tipo, seu Login está em Minúsculo (primeira Letra do Nome da Função e Nome da Pasta).

**Seria tipo isso:**

Arquivo Routes.js

```
import Logon from "./pages/Logon";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Logon} />
        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Arquivo Logon.js

```
export default function Logon() {
    try {
      history.push("/profile");
    } catch (err) {
      alert(`Algo deu errado: ${err}`);
    }
  }

  return (  );
}
```

Arquivo Profile.js

```
export default function Profile() {
  return (
    <div className="profile-container">
         Hello Word!!!
    </div>
  );
}
```

obs: Se você tivesse colocado o seu código escrito, ao invés de foto, eu teria editado ele.